# How to save an object graph with EntityFramework, lazy load disabled, proxy disabled and entities are non trackable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is the situation I am into using EF.

1. Repository gets an instance of A and returns to the presentation tier (i.e. MVC controllers)
2. The controllers change certain properties on A's instance and the given it back to persist.
3. Before persisting, I need to figure out what change was done to the object and validate if the change is permitted or not.
4. To compare the change, I need the old instance from the database.
5. But EF returns the same dirtied instance, so I cannot compare them.

What I tried doing:
Class Structure

```
public Class A {
 public B B {get;set;}
}

public class B {
  public ICollection<A> As {get;set;}
  public C c { get; set;}
}
public class C {
}
```

B and C map to the same database table.

1. Though it's because EF is tracking the old instance and since save has yet been called on the instance, so it's returning back the same inatce.
2. So I turned off lazy loading, proxy gen, and return the objects as non-trackable for the repository.
3. Now EF returns fresh record from the DB, but If changed some property on A, then in the B's collection of A, it loads only the instance of A that I changed, not the entire collection.
4. When If I want to create a new A and save, I do the following

   B b = GetSomeOldB();
   A a = new A();
   a.B = b
   a.Save();
5. So I essentially I add the new A to the context and call SaveChanges.
6. Ef returns and exception that "Unable to cast C to B".

**Basically, all I want is to get the old object graph from the context when I ask for, compare with the dirtied one the giving the dirtied to persist.**

Would really appreciate any help!!

Here is the solution that finally implemented:
1. Turned back on the Tracking and proxy creation
2. Get the orginal copy from EF. 
3. Wrote this generic method to hydrate a new instance of the entity

```
public ICollection<T> GetOriginalCollection<T>(ICollection<T> changedCollection) where T : class {
      ICollection<T> original = new Collection<T>();
      foreach (var item in changedCollection) {
          //Dont return the newly added ones to the original collection
          if (_context.Entry(item).State != EntityState.Added){
              original.Add(GetOriginal(item));
          }
      }
      return original;
  }

public T GetOriginal<T>(T changedEntity) where T : class {
      Func<DbPropertyValues, Type, object> getOriginal = null;
      getOriginal = (originalValues, type) =>
      {
          object original = Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
          foreach (var ptyName in originalValues.PropertyNames) {
              var property = type.GetProperty(ptyName);
              object value = originalValues[ptyName];
              //nested complex object
              if (value is DbPropertyValues) { 
                  property.SetValue(original, getOriginal(value as DbPropertyValues, property.PropertyType));
              } else{
                  property.SetValue(original, value);
              }
          }
          return original;
      };
      return (T)getOriginal(_context.Entry(changedEntity).OriginalValues, typeof(T));
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at [breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/). You'll instantly fall in love :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is working in disconnected environment. You can attach disconnected entities and provide what changed in the graph by specifying its EntityState. If you want you can create Interface like IObjectState and implement in your models to find out what exactly changed in the graph.

Comment: Thanks @Krishna. This is how fixed it. Turned the AutoDetection back to on and the proxy creation and get the original copy when needed from EF. I've the code snippets

Comment: You should also implement an IsRowVersion field in anticipation of concurrency conflicts.